# Is it possible to react to an AJAX response from outside the xhttp object?

Tags: javascript

I have a unified AJAX request that always does the same thing (fetch data and display it in a table).

I'd like to extend this functionality now. I have a table where I can select table rows and they will become marked.

The problem now is: If I use the pagination to go to a different page and back, the mark on every row is lost.

I'd like to call a function that marks the rows again. How do I call the function after my original AJAX completes - without modifying the original AJAX's `onreadystatechange`?

Essentially, I'm looking for something like "document.onajaxcompletion"

It doesn't matter if it executes on any non-specific AJAX call either

Pseudo-code:

```
document.addEventListener("ajaxcompletion", function() { myRowUpdater(); });
```

Comment: There is no global "ajax completion" event, but even if there were it's not clear how that would help with the described problem. It sounds like you want to make part of your `onreadystatechange` handler a separate function, and then call it from two places (`onreadystatechange` and also pagination or similar), but without more information, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Does the AJAX completion callback insert HTML into the document? How exactly does the pagination work? Does it use AJAX, too? Also, we really need to know why don't want to / can't modify the existing callback.

Comment: jQuery has: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: @mplungjan - Provided you use jQuery for the ajax, yes. OP doesn't seem to be using it at all.

Comment: I know, perhaps a reason to change

Comment: Pagination does the same thing, it sends a request to fetch data at the calculated offset, then on completion inserts the innerHTML of the table. I'd like to solve it in vanilla JS if possible.

Comment: It's not really clear what problem your having here, you must already waiting for the ajax to complete, or you wound't have any data to populate the grid.  `the mark on every row is lost.`, but that has nothing to do with doing an ajax request, you need to store the marks somewhere, maybe SessionStorage / LocalStorage, or even just an object if this is a SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with MutationObserver API to monitor the change to the Table's innerHTML in the end. It works perfectly.

```
const myObserver = new MutationObserver(myUpdateTableRowMarks);
myObserver.observe(document.getElementById("mytable_tbody"), { childList: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.

The long answer will depend on how you are recording the *"mark on every row"* with the AJAX request.

If that *marking* is recorded in a database, then your return to the page should (could) be corrected by the rendering of the HTML getting the data from the database.

If the *marking* is recorded browser side with `localStorage` (as an example), then reloading the page should check the `localStorage` during `window.onload` and correct the *marked* items.

These are only two possible solutions. Neither use AJAX to correct the HTML on reload.

It is possible you need to extend the functionality of the AJAX request to record the *marking* event. That information is missing from your question.

Possible flow:

- User loads page
- During `window.onload`, JavaScript creates an `onclick` event listener
- Member clicks item, item state is changed and event listener is called
- event listener passes AJAX request to record page and returns a "success" or "fail" response and records the action in a database (or not on a fail)
- on "success", the item state is confirmed or changed
- on "fail", state is reverted and member is informed of issue
- member leaves page
- on return to page, database is check and the recorded events are populated.